# Wordpress - add_menu_page, [ $this, 'function' ] not a valid class name or object

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I would like to understand why I cannot use [ $this, 'function' ] within it's own class.

This works:

**init.php**

```
if ( is_admin() )
{
    require ( dirname ( __FILE__ ) . '/inc/admin/Admin.php' );
    add_action('admin_menu', ['Mango\Admin', 'adminMenu'] );
}
```

**/inc/admin/Admin.php** - Version 1 (working)

```
<?php namespace Mango;

class Admin
{
    public function adminMenu()
    {
    //this is the main item for the menu
    add_menu_page(
        'Mango Settings', //page title
        'Mango Settings', //menu title
        'manage_options', //capabilities
        'mango-settings', //menu slug
        [ 'Mango\Admin', 'settingsPage' ] // LOOK HERE *******
    );
    }

    public function settingsPage()
    {
        echo 'This is a test';
    }
}
```

**/inc/admin/Admin.php** - Version 2 (not working)

```
<?php namespace Mango;

class Admin
{
    public function adminMenu()
    {
    //this is the main item for the menu
    add_menu_page(
        'Mango Settings', //page title
        'Mango Settings', //menu title
        'manage_options', //capabilities
        'mango-settings', //menu slug
        [ $this, 'settingsPage' ] // LOOK HERE *******
    );
    }

    public function settingsPage()
    {
        echo 'This is a test';
    }
}
```

Error Message: `Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in /.../wp-includes/plugin.php on line 429`

I don't really understand why I cannot register `[ $this, 'settingsPage' ]` with the add_menu_page hook. Surely the working version 1 is needlesly creating a 2nd copy of the Mango\Admin class?

Can anybody shed some light on this for me please?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little late for an answer, but it probably would help others too;

If the function is a member of a class within the plugin it should be
referenced as array( $this, 'function_name' )

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page

```
class Admin
{
    public function adminMenu()
    {
    //this is the main item for the menu
     add_menu_page(
        'Mango Settings', //page title
        'Mango Settings', //menu title
        'manage_options', //capabilities
        'mango-settings', //menu slug
        array( $this, 'settingsPage' ) // LOOK HERE *******
    );
    }

    public function settingsPage()
    {
        echo 'This is a test';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for having the foresight to post the correct answer to an old question. Your answer is over 6 years old and it still helped me!